# Define a function for a Log[b] which gives 0 when a==0

Tags: function-construction

I need a function aLogb[a,b] which:

1) Returns `a Log[b]` when `a` is a number, except it returns 0 when `a==0`. `b` can be a number or symbolic.

2) Returns `If[a==0,0,a Log[b]]` (unevaluated) when `a` is symbolic. `b` can be a number or symbolic.

Can't seem to get it right.

Comment: It sounds like you've already written the function. Maybe you're just missing the underscores? `aLogb[a_, b_] := If[a == 0, 0, a Log[b]]` seems like it should do what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is exactly as you basically already wrote

```
aLogb[a_, b_] := If[a == 0, 0, a Log[b]]
```

since when `a` is symbolic, *Mathematica* doesn't know if it's a number or zero, or anything, so it just leaves the `If` statement unevaluated.

Another way using pattern specifications to determine the output

```
aLogb[0, b_] = 0;
aLogb[a_?NumericQ, b_] := a Log[b]
aLogb[a_Symbol, b_] := Unevaluated@If[a == 0, 0, a Log[b]]
aLogb[0, b]
aLogb[π, b]
aLogb[a, b]
```

> 0
>
> π Log[b]
>
> If[a == 0, 0, a Log[b]]